# Return a single row from a Strongly Typed Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset

In my C# ASP.Net project I am using a xsd dataset to link to my database. I want to create a function return a single row from the strongly typed datatable but I'm running into a little difficulty doing this in C#. I have previously done this in VB.Net successfully using the code:

```
Public Function dr() As DataSet1.UsersRow
    Dim ta As New DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter
    Dim dt As DataSet1.UsersDataTable = ta.GetData
    Return dt.Rows(0)
End Function
```

My C# version of the code is:

```
public DataSet1.UsersRow dr()
{
    DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
    DataSet1.UsersDataTable dt = ta.GetData;
    return dt.Rows(0);
}
```

I get the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'MyProject.DataSet1.UsersRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I return my strongly typed row in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get it strongly typed using

`dt[0];`

Comment: Yes your right @PHeiberg, although not quite as you put it. It's not `dt.Users[0];` its just `dt[0];`

Comment: Yes, my mind must have slipped. I somehow must have gotten the impression that `dt` was a DataSet. Fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to explicitly convert the Rows item as I returned it:

```
public DataSet1.UsersRow dr()
{
    DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
    DataSet1.UsersDataTable dt = ta.GetData();
    return (DataSet1.UsersRow)dt.Rows(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient solution would be to add a query to the tableadapter along the lines of SELECT TOP 1  .. . FROM users, (or more generally, add a WHERE clause to return the required row.)
That way you are not pulling the entire table back just to retrieve one row.

Comment: how would you add a query to the above mentioned solution by sausagefingers?

Comment: Add a query in the designer - rt-click the tableadapter, select Add, Query.